# Segue from ViewController to first tab of TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift3

I've created a tabbed application. In the first tab (ViewController+TableView), it shows results taken from DB. I've a button that opens another ViewController in which user can filter results (for "city", for example).

Now, How can I return to the First tabbed page with a segue? Because I need to pass parameters in order to do a query to DB. If I create a segue between this page and the first ViewController it doesn't show tabbed menu.

Thank you guys.

Comment: You need to use an unwind segue to go back

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what are you trying to achieve is to pass data from one tab to another.

*"Now, How can I return to the First tabbed page **with a segue?** **Because I need to pass parameters in order to do a query to DB.**"*

Actually, you don't have to perform a segue to pass the data, instead you can do the following:

```
// somewhere in your code when you need to pass data to another tab viewController:
if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
    let secondTabViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as! SecondViewController
    // let's assume that you want to pass a string
    secondTabViewController.str = "my str!!"
}
```

SecondViewController:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    // here is the string that had been passed from the first tab viewController:
    var str:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // note that the output is: "Optional("my str!!")"
        print(str)

        // do optional binding:
        if let unwrappedStr = str {
            // output is: "my str!!"
            print(unwrappedStr)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: It was not what I mean.. I used Unwind segue and it works! :) Thank you